# Negative values geom_col() in R go below 0

Tags: r, ggplot2

I created a plot with `ggplot` but with negative values for some data bars and some columns go below 0 and that looks strange to me. How can I fix it (the value of the column shouldn't be changed)? I tried to use `limits =` in the body of the plot but it changed the value of the column.
Thank you!

```
div = 1000
sales_plot <- ggplot(sales, aes(week, net/(div*div))) +  
geom_col() +
  labs(x = "", y = "Net Value, RUB", title = "Sales by week, RUB") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -30, vjust = 1, size = 7)) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = unit_format(unit = "M")) +
  stat_summary(fun.y = sum, aes(label = paste(format(round(as.numeric(..y..),1), big.mark = ",", nsmall = 0, digits = 0),
                                              "M", sep = " " )),
               geom = "text", vjust = -2, size = 2.5)
```

[image]

Comment: If you want to change the out-of-bounds behaviour of scales, so you can set whatever limits, you could use `scale_y_continuous(..., oob = scales::oob_keep)`. Or do `coord_cartesian(ylim = ...)`.

Comment: What arguments should I choose for `oob_keep`? Or it goes without any argument? I tried to write it in `scale_y_continuos` but nothing happened, the penultimate columns goes below 0 anyway

Comment: The `oob_keep` is supposed to be passed a function, so you give the argument that function. You should use it together with `limits = ...`.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the data I can guess that the `net` column contains some negative number. I would recommend you summarize the weekly sales before graph them. As I don't have actual data here is my pseudo code.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

sales_summary <- sales %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarize(net_value = net / (div * div))

sales_plot <- ggplot(data = sales_summary, aes(x = week, y = net_value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(vjust = -2, size = 2.5) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Net Value, RUB", title = "Sales by week, RUB") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -30, vjust = 1, size = 7)) +
  scale_y_continuous(label = unit_format(unit = "M"), expand = c(0, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the reason is that I grouped values by several fields and one of the columns corresponding to the second field contains some negative values (although I didn't use it when I created the plot). The simple solution I found - just remove the second field and group only by weeks. I thought there would be a simple way without changing the initial data table with only adjusting the layers of the plot.